# How to use gcc compiling flags in R?

Tags: r, c

I'm using the following lines in an R file to compile a C file:

```
system2('R', c('CMD', 'SHLIB', 'My_C_File.c'))
dyn.load(paste0("My_C_File", .Platform$dynlib.ext))
```

I would like to optimize as much as possible the speed of this C code.
So I want to use the gcc `-O3` flag.

How do I insert this flag in the previous 2 lines?

Comment: why not rccp? then you can use  Makevars and Makevars.win

Comment: Because I already coded everything in C.

Comment: ???? https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/07/using-r-calling-c-code-with-rcpp/

Comment: Thanks. I found a way with `withr`: `with_makevars(c(CFLAGS = "-O3"), system("R CMD SHLIB --preclean -c foo.c"))` (example from the `withr` documentation)

Comment: The canonical answer is to edit either the file `~/.R/Makevars` or to set environment variables such as `PKG_CFLAGS`, `PKG_CXX11FLAGS` and so on.  It's all pretty well document and _will_ get picked up by `R CMD COMPILE` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Dirk Eddelbuettel. The (obvious) advantage I see with this method is its automatised character. Editing the file `~/.R/Makevars` or setting environment variables is manual: as my code is meant to be shared, I don't want the users to be obliged to manually change such files or environment variables.

Comment: Well if "my code is meant to be shared" the you *really* want a package and specifying this in `src/Makevars`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with `withr`: `with_makevars(c(CFLAGS = "-O3"), system("R CMD SHLIB --preclean -c foo.c"))` (example from the `withr` documentation)

Comment: That's really not a very good approach. See my comment above, the _Writing R Extensions_ manual, or a bazillion prior questions. The `inline` package can also help you make this less manual.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why it is not a very good approach.
Thanks for `inline`, I'm looking into it.

Comment: You enforce a dependency on another package when all you _really_ need is `Sys.setenv(CFLAGS="-O3")` (which, as an aside, is likely already a local default from R).  The `system()` call is clumsys.  R has functions for that already -- follow the implementation of the various `R CMD ...` commands.  Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Yes, I know, I indeed need a new package in my approach. Well, I didn't know `CFLAGS` was an environmental variable in the first place. BTW the flag `-O3` doesn't appear in my default `winshlib.mk` file; the default compiler flags are anyway not mentioned in the  _Writing R Extensions_ manual. My experience until now is that it's all very cryptic and not well documented. "The system() call is clumsys. R has functions for that already": I don't understand what you mean. In my code I used `system2('R', c('CMD', 'SHLIB', '2._IGTs_-_Graph_routines_NoHash_C.c'))`.

Comment: The thing is that `R CMD ...` is just a driver for `make` (!!) where `CFLAGS` is a variable that can be set in a `Makefile` or via the env.var.  Fourty years of Unix practice you can trust without needed one-off clutches via a special R wrapper functions.  Trust the basic process!

Comment: OK, I see, it's cleaner to work directly with `Makefile` files. I will look into it. Thank you!

Comment: Hello again Dirk. I'm aware this is not a good practice to intertwine topics but I'm really struggling: I would be extremely grateful if you could share some insights on debugging of C code in R in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074077/how-do-i-debug-a-c-file-than-i-compile-from-r

Comment: Don't spread questions and across, and that other one is a very poor one. There are mailing lists.  There are blogposts, videos, even old-school books.  Buckle up, and study some.